# The thumbnails are not displayed on mobile device

Tags: angular, ionic2

My Code:

```
`<ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
          <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img src="../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          {{data.Comp}}<br> 
          {{data.Demand}}<br>
          <p> {{data.Desig}}<br></p>
          {{data.Place}}<br>
           {{data.when}}<br>
        </ion-item>`
```

Please let me know if anymore inputs I need to add.

Comment: Use `src="assets/.."` instead, without the `../`

Comment: Thank you, @devqon unable to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according this document https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#modifying-your-existing-project

> Move www/assets to src/assets.
>
> Move www/img to src/assets/img.
>
> Fix any paths to images in your app. For example, before the path may
>   look like  and now it should be .

your path should be `assets/..`